# How to generate a random string from ASCII characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, random, ascii

How can I build a simple string generator that creates and prints out a randomized string of 10 characters, including lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers and special characters from 0 to 127 of the ASCII table by typing the ASCII-character-number-range in the method? Not a variable like

```
    var possibleCharacters = "01234567890abcdefgh....."
```

A friend of me already built it in Java (see below), so how can I build that in JavaScript, also with a for-loop like in the Java example?

```
    public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int counter = 0; counter <= 9; counter++) {
        int randomNum = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 127);
        if(randomNum > 33) {
            System.out.print((char)randomNum);
        }else {
            counter--;
        }
    }
}
}
```

It should just generate something like "_e7N?:G&M0" i.e.

Comment: What is your attempt? You can use charCode.

Comment: @YongQuan Thanks, this looks good. Unfortunately as a newbie I don't have any clue how to write that method. I also don't understand the code of my friend, and why he wrote a `33` in the code. I have no clue how to write that whole password generator function

Comment: A function to to return the random string, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/7dcuobps/)

Comment: Thank you so much @shrys it's working! How can I upvote your comment as it is right below my thread and not in the general answers section?

Comment: I can post the answer if you want me to

Comment: @MrFrontend if you are planning to implement a password generator function, you CANNOT generate random string this way because [`Math.random()` is NOT cryptographically secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/181580/why-is-math-random-not-designed-to-be-cryptographically-secure). You have to use the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).

Comment: @YongQuan Thank you. Highly important to mention. But this does it for my exercise.

Comment: Both JavaScript and Java use the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set. So, the character code formulas would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function to return the random string:

```js
function getString() {
  var str = "";
  for (counter = 0; counter <= 9; counter++) {
    var randomNum = 0 + parseInt(Math.random() * 127);
    if (randomNum > 33) {
      str += String.fromCharCode(randomNum);
    } else {
      counter--;
    }
  }
  return str;
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(getString());
```

If you're attempting to generate numbers between 33 and 127:

```js
function getString() {
  var str = "";
  for (counter = 0; counter <= 9; counter++) {
    var randomNum = 0 + parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * (127 - 33 + 1) + 33));
    str += String.fromCharCode(randomNum);
  }
  return str;
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  console.log(getString());
```

Comment: Thanks again. Can you tell me in the fourth line (of both examples) what the "0" in `0 + parseInt` is about? When I delete it, it seems it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes I think it doesn't do anything, might as well omit it